# Displaying a numpy array as a grayscale image using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to code a homemade "neural network" for a perceptron-like algorithm. So I'm using a numpy array to act like the memory of neuron, and I want to display the memory state.

So my memory look like :

```
[[113.33333333 141.66666667  85. 113.33333333  85.141.66666667 113.33333333 113.33333333]
[ 85.113.33333333 113.33333333 170.170. 56.66666667  85. 85.]
[141.66666667 113.33333333 255. 85. 28.33333333 198.33333333 113.33333333 113.33333333]
[ 85. 113.33333333 198.33333333 0. 28.33333333 113.33333333  85. 85. ]
[141.66666667 113.33333333 226.66666667  28.33333333 0. 28.33333333 85. 85.]
[113.33333333 113.33333333 170.28.33333333  56.66666667 170. 85. 85.]
[141.66666667 141.66666667 255. 170. 141.66666667 170. 28.33333333 113.33333333]
[141.66666667  85. 113.33333333 141.66666667 113.33333333 56.66666667 141.66666667  85.]]
```

So it's a 8 by 8 array containing float beetween 0 and 255.

The problem is when I try to display it, using

```
cv2.imshow("Window", img)
```

I have a Black and White image displayed, but no grayscale.

Something like :

[How my image is displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CC744.png)

Do you have any idea how to force open cv to show the grayscale out of this image?

Comment: if it is an array of floats, the scale is from 0-1, if it is numpy.uint8 then the scale is from 0-255. You can do: `cv2.imshow("Window", np.uint8(img))`

Comment: That was it! thanks mate :)